# Changing a Local Variable With a Different Function

Tags: c++, function, local-variables

How can I change `number` in `get_number` using the function `increaseNumber` if `increaseNumber` has to be `void`?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void increaseNumber(int64_t number){
    number++;
}

int64_t get_number(){
    int64_t number = 0;
    increaseNumber(number);
    return number;
}

int main(void){

    cout << get_number();
}
```

If it is of any help, I have tried changing an array rather than an integer and that worked fine.

Comment: Pass the parameter as reference `void increaseNumber(int64_t& number){
    number++;
}`

Comment: Why does `increaseNumber` have to return `void`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared the function `increaseNumber` in such a way that the parameter is passed by value:

```
void increaseNumber( int64_t number )
```

That way, it is passed a copy of the value of the variable `number` of the function `get_number`. Therefore, modifying the variable `number` of the function `increaseNumber` will not change the variable `number` of the function `get_number`, as these are two separate variables.

If you instead want the original variable's value to be modified too, then you should not pass a copy of the variable's value, but you should instead declare the function in such a way that a reference to the original variable is passed:

```
void increaseNumber( int64_t& number )
```

That way, no copy of the original variable will be made, and your program should work as intended, without any further modifications being necessary.

The reason why using an array worked with you is that if you pass an array, it will [decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay), which is equivalent to a reference.

Comment: How about `int64_t* const number` and then `++(*number)`?

Comment: @digito_evo: Yes, passing the variable by pointer would be the C-style way of solving the problem, but passing the variable by reference is the common way to solve the problem in C++. In C++, there is [call by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm), [call by pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm) and [call by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm). In C, there is only the first two.